# How can I represent the number 2^1000 in C++?

Tags: c++

So, I was trying to do problem # 16 on Project Euler, from http://projecteuler.net if you haven't seen it. It is as follows:

```
2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.

What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to represent the number 2^1000 in C++. I am guessing there is a trick to this, but I am really stuck. I don't really want the answer to the problem, I just want to know how to represent that number as a variable, or if perhaps there is a trick, maybe someone could let me know?

Comment: You don't have to do it in C++, either. Off my head, `bcpow` in PHP will let you do that dead easy.

Comment: I thought of trying an unsigned long long int, but that only goes up to 2^64 − 1 from what I have read, if I remember correctly.

Comment: looks like a question from math olympiad.  probably a trick to getting it without coding anything.

Comment: Yes, there is a trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Represent it as a string. That means you need to write two pieces of code:

1. You need to write a piece of code to double a number, given that number as a string.
2. You need to write a piece of code to sum the digits of a number represented as a string.

With those two pieces, it's easy.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: 3. You need to write a piece of code to sum 2 numbers, given that the numbers are strings.

Comment: @maniek: Not needed in this case. You can just start with "1" and double it 1,000 times. Though it's probably no harder to write an addition function and double a number by adding it to itself. Doubling may be slightly easier because you don't have to deal with the case where the numbers have different numbers of digits.

Comment: This works, but (a) it's more complicated than using a bignum library, and (b) it misses the point of the question in exactly the same way that using a bignum library would.

Comment: @abarnert: How does this miss the point of the question? The point of the question is to force you to write your own code to handle long/large numbers, right?

Answer (score 8):

One good algorithm worth knowing for this problem:

```
2^1 = 2
2^2 = 2 x 2 = 2 + 2
2^3 = 2 x (2 x 2) = (2 + 2) + (2 + 2)
2^4 = 2 x [2 x ( 2 x 2)] = [(2 + 2) + (2 + 2)] + [(2 + 2) + (2 + 2)]
```

Thus we have a `recursive` definition for calculating a power of two in terms of the `addition` operation: `just add together two of the previous power of two.`

This [link](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/07/project-euler-problem-16-calculating.html) deals with this problem very well.

Comment: Who downvoted this? This is a great hint in the direction of solving the problem, with a link toward more hints (which still don't give away the entire solution). That's exactly the kind of thing people should be posting when people come here asking for solutions to Project Euler problems.

Comment: Great approach! Combine this with David's answer and this problem becomes easy as hell!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete program. The digits are held in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> digits;
    digits.push_back(1);        // 2 ** 0 = 1

    const int limit = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i != limit; ++i)
    {
        // Invariant: digits holds the individual digits of the number 2 ** i

        unsigned int carry = 0;
        for (auto iter = digits.begin(); iter != digits.end(); ++iter)
        {
            unsigned int d = *iter;
            d = 2 * d + carry;
            carry = d / 10;
            d = d % 10;
            *iter = d;
        }
        if (carry != 0)
        {
            digits.push_back(carry);
        }
    }

    unsigned int sum = std::accumulate(digits.cbegin(), digits.cend(), 0U);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works moderately fast (2s) for 16000, but unfortunately, is painfully slow for something like 96000. Any way to make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of this problem is to come up with a way of doing this without actually calculating 2^1000.

However, if you *do* want to calculate 2^1000—which may be a good idea, because it's a great way to test whether your other algorithm is correct—you're going to want some kind of "bignum" library, such as [`gmp`](http://gmplib.org/manual):

```
mpz_t two_to_1000;
mpz_ui_pow_ui(two_to_1000, 2, 1000);
```

Or you can use the [C++ interface](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html) to `gmp`. It doesn't do exponentiation, so the first part gets slightly more complicated instead of less, but it makes the digit-summing simpler:

```
mpz_class two_to_1000;
mpz_ui_pow_ui(two_to_1000.get_mpz_t(), 2, 1000);
mpz_class digitsum(0);
while (two_to_1000) {
    digitsum += two_to_1000 % 10;
    two_to_1000 /= 10;
}
```

(There's actually no reason to make `digitsum` an `mpz` there, so you may want to figure out how to prove that the result will fit into 32 bits, add that as a comment, and just use a `long` for `digitsum`.)

All that being said, I probably wouldn't have written this `gmp` code to test it, when the whole thing is a one-liner in Python:

```
 print(sum(map(int, str(2**1000))))
```

And, even though converting the bignum to a string to convert each digit to an int to sum them up is possibly the least efficient way to solve it, it still takes under 200us on the slowest machine I have here. And there's really no reason the double-check needs to be in the same language as the actual solution.

Comment: *"The whole point of this problem is to come up with a way of doing this without actually calculating 2^1000."* -- I don't think that's the case.  Project Euler is about solving problems in any way you find most convenient, through math, programming, or a combination thereof.  If you have a strong math background and can think of a way to solve it without actually calculating 2^1000, fine, but I don't think they actually expect you to do that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: If that were true, this would be a ridiculously easy question. It's a 1-liner in Python, and a 4-liner in any other language that has bignums either built-in or available as a library. But the problems are intended to require both "mathematical insights… and programming skills", not to be solved trivially by brute force. If you solve this problem (and problem 13, and various others) just by using (or simulating) bignums, you've missed the point.

Comment: It's problem 16 of 410.  It's supposed to be easy.  They get progressively harder as you go down the line.  In the early stages, brute force is usually adequate, but later on, things get much trickier.  That is to say "mathematical insights... and programming skills" eventually become absolutely essential.  Besides, the problem may seem easy to you, but for a young kid, not so much.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: OK, let me put it another way: If you solve problem 16 the brute-force way, you're not going to get past the first page of problems. The early problems can be used as a way to "warm up" for the later ones, or to build useful bits of insight and code that will help you… or you can just calculate 2^1000, check this one off, and later wonder why your solution to, say, #25 takes 3 weeks to run… I don't think it's at all helpful to push people down the latter path.

Answer (score -1):

You'd need a 1000 bit machine integer to represent 2^1000; I've never heard of a machine with such.  But there are a lot of big integer packages around, which do the arithmetic over as many machine words as are needed.  The simplest solution might be to use one of these.(Although given the particular operations you need, doing the arithmetic on a string, as David Schwartz suggested, might be appropriate.  In the general case, it's not a very good idea, but since all you're doing is multiplying by two, and then taking the decimal digits, it might work out well.)

Answer (score -1):

Since 2^10 is about 10^3, and 2^1000 = (2^10)^100 = (10^3)^100 = 10^300 (about).
So allocate an array like

```
char digits[ 300 ]; // may be too few
```

and store a value between 0 .. 9 in each char.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of just using a `string`? Then you don't have to try it, debug the crash you got because 300 was too few and you smashed the stack, and try again… Remember, the OP is trying to solve this in C++, not C.

Comment: The OP was asking how to store a number too big to fit in machine data types.  The above is to communicate the basic idea behind multi-precision arithmetic without extraneous details to confuse the concept.